# Docker container can't connect to the host machine database

Tags: mysql, docker, drupal-6

I tried to deploy a drupal 6 docker container that works with the host machine database (for testing purpose before deploying it to a remote database) but it just doesn't want to work despite following the different advices I found. ( particularly in this question [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) when it talks about host mode, so even if the question looks alike it doesn't feel like it is a duplicate )

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

COPY . /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80

RUN chmod o+w /var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php &&\
    chmod o+w /var/www/html/sites/default/files &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev &&\
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ &&\
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli gd mbstring pdo pdo_mysql &&\
    docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    website:
        build: 
            context: ./drupal-6-lts
            network: host
        volumes:
            - ./drupal-6-lts:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 8080:80
```

For the database connection I specified these settings :

Driver : mysqli
Host : 127.0.0.1:8889 (the mysql port is 8889, I also tried to replace 127.0.0.1 by localhost)
And the right username, password and database name.

The drupal installation does work when I launch it with MAMP only, but it seems that it can't do the link to the db when in the container despite the `network: host` statement in docker-compose.yml

When I try Do Trung Duc solution I get this error when executing docker compose build :

> services.network_mode must be a mapping

Comment: Have you tried to connect database with physical IP?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `network: host`, use `network_mode: host`. Also, if you use `network_mode: host`, you won't need to add `ports: - 8080: 80`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    website:
        build: 
            context: ./drupal-6-lts
    volumes:
        - ./drupal-6-lts:/var/www/html
    network_mode: host
```